# Microsoft Graph API returns 400 URL specified is invalid with /drive/root/children

Tags: sharepoint, microsoft-graph-api

I am trying to use MS Graph API to read files from a SharePoint form library but while the drives command works any combination to get the files fails. It should be noted I am the owner of the site with full permissions. Using the online Graph explorer tool, and granting the permissions for `files.read.all` and `sites.read.all` the command to get the default drive (documents) works:

`https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/myportal.sharepoint.com:/sites/mysite:/drive`

According to the documentation [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/driveitem-list-children?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http) the next command should show the files in the default drive:

`https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/myportal.sharepoint.com:/sites/mysite:/drive/root/children`

However the explorer throws the 400 error saying "Url specified is invalid." Same thing happens if I try to enter the folder ID.

Is there an error in the permissions or the URL or could the online explorer tool be limited?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To list SharePoint library(drive), use

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/siteid/drive/root/children
```

Test demo:

[image]

Comment: It would seem you can get the default drive information by using the site "name", but if you cannot string together the syntax for getting the children. When attempting to get the files it looks like you need to substitute the site ID. I will go back and check the documentation to see if it state something about this and I just missed it.

Comment: I am facing the same issue. Did you manage to find a solution?